# Create a SQL trigger to record the literal, textual query itself

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, triggers, database-trigger

I'd like to log all DELETE and UPDATE queries made on a particular table (no need to log INSERT operations), and record them in a different table.

I understand there are numerous tutorials and references demonstrating how to capture and log various fields (eg https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/sqlite-triggers.php) , but I'm actually interested in the literal query string itself before it is parsed into a tabular format, eg, to record:

```
|kittenLogID| kittenID|            query                     |
|-----------|---------|--------------------------------------|
|1          |1        |"DELETE from Kittens WHERE kittenID=1"|
```

I'm interested in doing this in both sqlite3 syntax as well as how it differs in the trigger syntax of MS SQL.

In sqlite3, I expect something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER kittenLog
AFTER DELETE, UPDATE
On Kittens

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO kittenLog (kittenID, MY_QUERY)   --how do I get this MY_QUERY thing I made up?
  SELECT new.kittenID as kittenID, MY_QUERY
  FROM new
  WHERE new.kittenID = old.kittenID
END

END
```

In MS SQL, I would expect something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER kittenLog_delete
AFTER DELETE
On Kittens

DECLARE @data XML;
SET @data = EVENTDATA();

BEGIN
  INSERT kittenLog (kittenID, query)
  VALUES (d.kittenID, @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as MY_QUERY)
  FROM deleted d
END

END


CREATE TRIGGER kittenLog_update
AFTER UPDATE
On Kittens

DECLARE @data XML;
SET @data = EVENTDATA();

BEGIN
  INSERT kittenLog (kittenID, query)
  VALUES (d.kittenID, @data.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as MY_QUERY)
  FROM inserted d
END

END
```

It is not clear to me what is in this `EVENTDATA()` object and how to rephrase this, but I think it is the key in the latter.

If helpful, my Kitten Tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Kittens (
  kittenID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  human_name text,
);

CREATE TABLE kittenLog (
  kittenLogID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  kittenID INTEGER,
  query text,
  timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for MS SQL. Do not use `text` datatype is deprecated and should not be used. Here are scripts

```
CREATE TABLE Kittens (
    kittenID INT PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1)
    , human_name varchar(8000) --use varchar(max) if you think that 8000 is not enough for you
);
CREATE TABLE kittenLog (
    kittenLogID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY identity(1,1),
    kittenID INT,
    query varchar(8000),
    timestamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

create trigger kittenLog_audit
on Kittens
after update, delete
as

declare @kittenID int
declare @execStr varchar(100)
declare @query varchar(8000)

if exists (select 1 from deleted) --either delete or update
    begin
        select @kittenID = kittenID from deleted

        declare @inputbuffer table (
          EventType nvarchar(30) 
          , Parameters int 
          , EventInfo nvarchar(255)
         )

         set @execStr = 'dbcc inputbuffer(' + str(@@SPID) + ')'

         insert into @inputbuffer 
         exec (@ExecStr)

         set @query = (select EventInfo from @inputbuffer)


        insert into kittenLog (kittenID, query)
        values (@kittenID, @query)
    end
```